# Website seems to be fine on everything but iphone

Tags: iphone, web

I am building a website for a friend and it's just about done, apart from a bit more content, but now he tells me that it doesn't look right on his iphone. I have checked it on Safari, Opera, IE, Chrome and Firefox on laptop, and on my Android phone and on web-based iphone emulators and everything looks fine. I had him check on someone else's iphone and 1 of the problems goes but the other remains. My site is pretty basic, html and css only, but I am the first to admit that as I am new to this my code could probably be better.

The first issue is that above the header his iphone shows there are what's best described as 5 red bricks evenly spaced along the top. This doesn't show on his mates iphone.

The second issue is that on the "products" page, the right column text under the pictures isn't lined up properly, which is the case on his mates iphone. I don't know what to do here because if I alter the padding I used to line things up, it won't be right on every other browser/device.

I'm not sure what I'm best posting on here, the whole code for the site seems too much, but whatever needed to help answer just let me know. The site address for the products page is http://www.doortodoordrinksyork.com/products.html

Like I say I'm new to this so please keep answers simple.

Thanks in advance.

David.

PS Would appreciate anyone with an iphone telling me how the site displays on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Mac, you can use the iOS Simulator tool that comes with [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) to test out your site in a virtual iPhone/iPod. You can even compare different versions of the built-in browser, which I think is what's causing the difference between your mate's devices.

In general, well-built sites will 'work' without modification on mobile devices, but you may want to look into [media queries](http://mediaqueri.es/), a CSS feature that lets you target specific screen sizes with different rules.